# overflow-x and overflow-y is not working correctly in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a common table to hide extra text in cells using below css code

```
.table td{
   display: table-cell;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 250px;
   width: inherit;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Html code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> # </th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-xs">Code</th>
                                            <th>Category</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-xs">Location</th>
                                            <th>More</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                            <td>21</td>
                                            <td class="sorting_1">XXXXXXXX</td>
                                            <td>00000000</td>
                                            <td>xxxxxxxxxx</td>
                                            <td>No: xx/x</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                                        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-blue dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> 
                                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                                            <li role="presentation">
                                                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="../asset/edit?id=57">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li role="presentation">
                                                                <a data-toggle="modal" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#model57">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

There is a button in a cell on each table and it shows a dropdown when click on the button like bellow.
[image]

For the above code dropdown works correctly in firefox, but in chrome it hide the dropdown menu like below.
[image]

I need to make a common css code for work in every table. How can i fix this issue in chrome?

Here is the fiddle example. Check it with firefox and chrome
https://jsfiddle.net/udarazz/qhane23o/1/

Comment: Please provide your code to check.

Comment: Remove overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: @ankitapatel which code do you need? Html code?

Comment: @Udara  yes html code.

Comment: .table td:last-child{
overflow-y:auto;
}

Comment: What's the css For that drop-down just upload here.

Comment: @ankitapatel html code added

Comment: @Udara not this way. Provide your full code. Only this code is not useful.

Comment: @ankitapatel Tables are generate with database. Then how can i add whole code here. This is a sample html code.

Comment: @Udara but in your code design is not coming and dropdown also not working then how can i solve this?

Comment: @ankitapatel i have added jsfiddle example, please check it.

Comment: @Udara k thnx i will check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153085/discussion-between-ankita-patel-and-udara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```js
$(".btn-group").parent().parent("td").addClass("drp_menu");
```

```css
.table td{
   display: table-cell;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 250px;
   width: inherit;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   overflow-x: visible;
}
td.drp_menu {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> # </th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th >Code</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th >Location</th>
          <th>More</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr role="row" class="odd">
          <td>21</td>
          <td class="sorting_1">XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
          <td>00000000</td>
          <td>xxxxxxxxxx</td>
          <td>No: xx/x</td>
          <td>
              <div align="center">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-blue dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                          <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> 
                          <span class="caret"></span>
                      </a>
                      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                          <li role="presentation">
                              <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="../asset/edit?id=57">
                                  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li role="presentation">
                              <a data-toggle="modal" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#model57">
                                  <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove
                              </a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

What if to try to set `z-index` for that `block` with menu?

**UPD:** As I can see the problem not with TD but with `ul.dropdown-menu.pull-right` in it

**UPD2:**

```
.table td ul.dropdown-menu.pull-right{
  display:block; 

}
```

**UPD3:**
https://codepen.io/Leo240/pen/Jymqrz

Comment: Then i think you must also to give the HTML code example.

Comment: can you please share the codepen link with your answer. It will help others as well

Comment: @Udara Done. I've added it.

Comment: Thank. I will check it

Comment: in that code you are using  `overflow-y: visible;overflow-x: visible;` for `table td`. It will disable my hiding extra text in other cells

Answer (score 0):

Use this style for last column of table.

```
table tr td:last-child {
   text-overflow: initial;
   overflow-y: visible;
   overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Comment: This is work for only this table. But i need to make a common table css code. Because sometimes the button is not in last column

Comment: u can use hasChild method like this  table tr td:hasChild(< button), I used this once. It will search the button in td

Comment: its CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

its selector level 4: in detail you can read this http://chris.house/blog/thinking-about-the-has-css-selector/